# Issues with yarn test using react-native-ble-manager

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RSD4.png)

I've created a BLE project and I'm facing several issues when trying to perform basic unit tests with the dependency. I couldn't find any resources on YouTube or the official library repository regarding this matter. I'm not sure how to proceed now, as I'm required to go through this testing routine. I can't release the project without passing yarn install, yarn lint, and finally yarn test. Unfortunately, the test always fails. Is there any alternative to make it work without resorting to complex mocking?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)